# Possessive pronouns and verb with -ing form

Tags: verbs, pronouns

I'm looking for the rules concerning when you use *possessive pronouns* combined with a *verb of "-ing" form*. What's the combination called and how does it work?

Examples:

- Thanks to **my going** to school I know a lot of things.
- I object to **his going** to the dentist.

Can you also say this?

- Thanks to **me** going to school I know a lot of things.
- I object to **him** going to the dentist.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-pronoun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called *gerunds*. Gerunds are derived from verbs and serve as nouns. Since they serve as a noun, they need possessive case of nouns to modify them. That's the reason, your latter examples sound ungrammatical.

> I object to *his (possessive)* going

and **not**...

> I object to *him (not possessive)* going

A good reference from [Washington State University's page](https://public.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/gerundspro.html)

> Verb forms ending in “-ing” can function as nouns and are sometimes preceded by pronouns. Such verb/noun forms are called “gerunds.” You’ll often see sentences like this:
>
> “I didn’t appreciate **him** returning the car with the gas tank empty.”
>
> **But** “returning” is a gerund, so it should be preceded by a possessive pronoun:
>
> “I didn’t appreciate **his** returning the car. . . .”

Good question :)